# Facing issue by using some operation in MsSQL query

Tags: sql-server

i am new to Mssql server i am trying to migrate Mysql queries to Mssql on the process facing issue with this query.

query is:

```
SELECT  converT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(converT(datetimeoffset,created), 'America/New_York')),  
        SUM(case when channel='FACEBOOK' then 1 else 0 end) AS  Messenger,
        SUM(case when channel='EMAIL' then 1 else 0 end) AS  Email,  
        SUM(case when channel='ECHO' then 1 else 0 end) AS Echo  
FROM   Conversation  
WHERE tenant_id=2 AND createdBy_id in(3) 
AND   created >= '2018-11-01 06:00:01'  
GROUP BY year(created), month(created),  DATEPART(week,created),day(created) 
ORDER BY created ASC;
```

And the error which i am facing is:

Column `Conversation.created` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

When I am trying to execute to the query without aggregate function its working the combination of `converT` and `sum` is not working. Can anybody help me out this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: rule of thumb, whatever column not in aggregate need to be in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Meaning you need to add this `converT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(converT(datetimeoffset,created), 'America/New_York'))` to the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to add this  `converT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(converT(datetimeoffset,created)` in `Group By` as you already grouped other fields and you want to show this result in `Group By`:

```
SELECT  
    converT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(converT(datetimeoffset,created), 'America/New_York')),  
    SUM(case when channel='FACEBOOK' then 1 else 0 end) AS  Messenger,
    SUM(case when channel='EMAIL' then 1 else 0 end) AS  Email,  
    SUM(case when channel='ECHO' then 1 else 0 end) AS Echo  
FROM   Conversation  
WHERE tenant_id=2 AND createdBy_id in(3) 
AND   created >= '2018-11-01 06:00:01'  
GROUP BY converT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(converT(datetimeoffset,created), year(created), 
    month(created),  DATEPART(week,created),day(created) 
ORDER BY created ASC;
```

This error means that you've got `SUM` of `channel` field - one row, but SQL Server
has also many rows with `created` column and it does not know what row should be chosen.

Comment: Thank you for the response it's working with exclude the order by

Comment: SELECT  converT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(converT(datetimeoffset,created), 'America/New_York')),  
        SUM(case when channel='FACEBOOK' then 1 else 0 end) AS  Messenger,
        SUM(case when channel='EMAIL' then 1 else 0 end) AS  Email,  
        SUM(case when channel='ECHO' then 1 else 0 end) AS Echo  
FROM   Conversation  
WHERE tenant_id=2 AND createdBy_id in(3) 
AND   created >= '2018-11-01 06:00:01'  
GROUP BY converT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(converT(datetimeoffset,created), 'America/New_York')),
year(created), month(created),  DATEPART(week,created),day(created)

Comment: @VrandaRaghuwanshi just add `ORDER BY created` to the end of your query. And it should work.